# XCode 6.3 and iPhone 5s iOS 8.3 (12F70)

Tags: ios, xcode6.3, ios8.3

After install XCode 6.3 my device moved to Ineligible section. Select by product->Destination works ok, but i want to fix issue and not bypass it.
I think problem is in 8.3 version. Device is running on 12F70 version, but there is no such folder in Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
There is only 8.3 (12F69)
How can I fix this?

Comment: i think you can fix the issue by changing deployment target into 8.0 or later..